# Debug WSH JScripts in Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jscript, wsh

Is it possible to debug a JScript targeting Windows Scripting Host (WSH) in Visual Studio Express 2013?

Note: the code uses the `GetObject` method, which is not permitted in Internet Explorer anymore for security reason. So the IE debugger is not an option.

I see an explicit template for inserting WSH files (besides JScript files) in VS Express for Web, but I don't understand how to run them in VS debugger.

I tried to debug externally with administrator privileges:

```
cscript.exe  //x //d script.js
cscript.exe  //d script.js
cscript.exe  //x script.js
cscript.exe  //x //d script.wsh
cscript.exe  //d script.wsh
cscript.exe  //x script.wsh
```

To see if the problem is with my system Win7 x64, I installed the prehistoric  Microsoft Script Debugger for NT and:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe  //x //d script.js
c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe  //x //d script.wsh
```

How can I go back to modern times?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to do it with express but you can do it with the community edition.  You need to do this to the registry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script\Settings]
"JITDebug"=dword:00000001
```

You might want to add it to the tools/external tools in visual studio to make life easier.  Starting with cscript //x //d will prompt for the debugger.